# Google VR Unity SDK - Unable to Detect Touch in VR Mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr

I am using GVR Unity SDK Version: 1.1 with Unity 5.5.0f3. I need to display a button similar to the Gear Icon that is rendered by the Google VR SDK. This button should accept touches and should be visible at all times. The issue with using a Button created in the Unity Canvas is that it does not process touches because the GVR Input Module takes precedence over the StandAlone input Module.

I have looked at the google vr sdk code and have found that the gear icon is rendered using OpenGL calls in the PostRender.cs file but still am not able to find where the touch is processed. Beyond this I am stuck as I dont have much knowledge of OpenGL.

My question : How do I render a button on top of the existing UI (so that it is visible at all times just like the gear icon) and get it to accept touches (by calling a function in my code).

Answer (score 0):

I know that you have to do some recasting from the controller to the UI.  There is a demo scene called "Scrolling UI".  Try checking there to see if there is something that can help out.

I'm not a hundred percent sure, but just some advice to the right direction.

Hope you find your answer!

Comment: I will check it out but from my understanding what you are talking about is for gaze based controller. Any way will have a look.

Comment: I had a look at the example and it does not help. It works with the pointer and not with touch.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found for enabling regular touch inputs on top of the VR scene is to use a Screen Space - Overlay canvas with a regular Graphic-Raycaster and add a Standalone Input Modul to the EventSystem game object.
This way the buttons in that canvas are clickable.
Hope it helps.